# Delphi - passing TStringList to IdHTTP.Get method similar to .Post method

Tags: delphi

Working code example using `IdHTTP.Post` method:

```
var
param: TStringList;
spost: string;
...
param := TStringList.Create;
param.Add('something=from somewhere');
param.Add('something1=from somewhere1');
param.Add('something2=from somewhere2');
...
IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
spost := IdHTTP.Post('https://url.com/v1/something?', param);
Memo1.Lines.Add(spost); //dump the response to a Memo
param.Free;
```

How do you pass (do the same/elicit the same behavior) a `TStringList` to `IdHTTP.Get` method similar to how you would do when using `IdHTTP.Post` method?

Comment: [RFC7231, section 4.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1): "_A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request._"

Comment: @AmigoJack Appreciate the heads up and link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GET request does not normally carry a body (some servers abuse this for non-standard purposes), so `TIdHTTP.Get()` does not have any overloads that accept body data as input.

The only way to send a body in a GET request with `TIdHTTP` is to call the `TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest()` method directly. However, it is declared as `protected`, so you will have to use a descendant/accessor class to reach it, eg:

```pascal
type
  TIdHTTPAccess = class(TIdHTTP)
  end;

TIdHTTPAccess(IdHTTP).DoRequest('GET', URL, ReqStream, RespStream, []);
```

Where `ReqStream` is an optional `TStream` containing the desired request body you want to send, and `RespStream` is an optional `TStream` to receive the response body.

Comment: Appreciate the, yet again, stellar answer. Thanks! :)